# JQuery function only works on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem i am having with me JQuery function is that it only works when i refresh the webpage, it is working this way on every browser. What i am trying to do is once all of the textfields in enclosed in a specific div container all have data inside them, i want the the container to insert the checkmark image. but currently this image only becomes visible after i have entered all of the data in the textfields AND refreshed the brower.

.rightbilling is the class of the div container whose textfields im trying to evalute and '#step1' is the fieldset that contains .rightbilling.

I have been trying to solve this for hours..help is greatly appreciated. if you need more info, let me know.

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
        var all_complete = true;    
    $(".rightbilling").find("input:text").each(function(){


        if ($(this).val() == '' ) {
            all_complete = false;
            return true;
        };


    if (all_complete) {
        $("#step_1")
        .animate({
            paddingBottom: "120px"
        })
        .css({
            "background-image": "url(images/check.png)",
            "background-position": "bottom center",
            "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
        });

        $("#step_2").css({
            opacity: 1.0
        });
        $("#step_2 legend").css({
            opacity: 1.0 // For dumb Internet Explorer
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Well, your function is only executed once on page load... it seems you want to periodically check whether the fields have been filled?

Comment: I've never used `$(document.body).ready(...)`, only `$(document).ready(...)`.  Could that be at issue?

Comment: in another post i saw that this:
$(window).load(function() {
was used to fix a similar problem but that didnt do anything different

Comment: I usually just use `$(...);`, same thing according to [jQuery API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @ScottSauyet  taking the .body out made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document.body).ready(
    function () {
        var validation = function () {
            var all_complete = true;
            $(".rightbilling").find("input:text").each(
                function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                        all_complete = false;
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (all_complete) {
                        $("#step_1").animate({
                            paddingBottom: "120px"
                        }).css({
                            "background-image": "url(images/check.png)",
                            "background-position": "bottom center",
                            "background-repeat": "no-repeat"
                        });
                        $("#step_2").css({
                            opacity: 1.0
                        });
                        $("#step_2 legend").css({
                            opacity: 1.0 // For dumb Internet Explorer
                        });
                    }
            });
        }
        validation();  //call it when the page is loaded
        $(".rightbilling").find("input:text").on("change",validation); //call it when input changes
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm. Just to be sure im on the right page, could you explain the logic behind why that works?

Comment: because you are calling the function when each element changes and not just on the page ready event.

Comment: how can i modify this code to take away the image if text is removed from a textfield after it has already validated?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using the document.ready function, your function is only being called when the page loads. You'll want to look into attaching an onChange listener to call your function when the input fields have been changed.

Comment: alright, that makes a lot of sense. how exactly do i implement that? ive only been working with jquery for a few days.

Comment: Judging by your code, you'll probably just want to replace $(document).ready() with $(".rightbilling").find("input:text").change()

Comment: @Luminously $(".rightbilling").find("input:text").change() had no affect on my code, now it no longer displays the check